# max of two random variables inequality

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be random variables.

Suppose we have $\mathbb{E}X_1 \geq  \mathbb{E}Y_1$ and $\mathbb{E}X_2 \geq \mathbb{E}Y_2$, is it necessarily the case $\mathbb{E}\max(X_1,X_2) \geq \mathbb{E}\max(Y_1,Y_2)$?

If it makes the problem easier, (it looks to me it cannot do any harm), we can make the additional assumption that  $X_1$ and $X_2$ are non-negatively correlated, so are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

I have tried to find a counter-example and so far I have failed.

A proof or counterexample to the statement with or without the additional assumptions would be hugely appreciated.

---

EDIT:

From the answer below, without the additional assumption, this problem is trivial. So here is the updated question. Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ and $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are positively correlated. Is the statement true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1,X_2$ be iid such that $X=N$ with probability $\frac 1N$ and $0$ with probability $\frac{N-1}{N}$ then $\mathbb E(X) = 1$ and $\mathbb E(\max(X_1,X_2) ) = 2-\frac 1N$

So letting $Y_1,Y_2$ be iid such that $Y=2N$ with probability $\frac 1{2N}$ and $0$ with probability $\frac{2N-1}{2N}$ gives  $\mathbb E(X) = \mathbb E(y) = 1$
but $\mathbb E(\max(Y_1,Y_2) ) = 2-\frac 1{2N} > \mathbb E(\max(X_1,X_2) )$.

Comment: i modified the question.

Comment: ah wait, i bet your example can be modified in a way that it would still be true for the extra condition just by taking the correlation to be very weak....

Comment: Yup, was about to do that

Comment: what a bugger! it looks blatantly obvious for the random variables I am dealing with, the conditions and the conclusion are all true, but I can't prove any of them. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Edit your question to say what your random variables are and what you're trying to prove, I'll have a look.

Comment: It is to do with American type option pricing and I think it would take up way too much of your time. Basically I am trying to compare to two option prices. The maximum occurs because the price of the option is the bigger of the exercising value or if you decide to hold it. However, if this interests, I will post it!

Comment: Probably not something I can help you with.  Good luck anyway

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1 = X_2 = 0$ with probability 1.

Let $Y_1 = -Y_2$, and $Y_1 = 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and $Y_1 = -3$ otherwise.

Then $E[Y_i] = -1$ and $E[X_i] = 0$

And $E[\max\{X_1,X_2\}] = 0$, but $E[\max\{Y_1,Y_2\}] = 1$

Comment: Hmm this is precisely the type of thing I didn't want. okay, let me modify the question. I am going to make the positive correlation a definite thing